# JAXB issues on restful web service

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jaxb, glassfish

i've tried to create RestFul Service on Netbeans 8.1 using GlassFish 4.1.1. After check if DB connection is established and write and load are available, I've some issues related to JAXB coding and encoding of Json passed as argument to java object. 
This is the log of when I try to pass a json file related to my model bean:

```
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
     org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb.WrappedValue not found by
     jaxb-api [2]   at
     org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
        at
     org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)
        at
     org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:1955)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    at
     org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb.JaxbClassLoader.loadClass(JaxbClassLoader.java:107)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)    at
     java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)    at
     org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jaxb.JaxbClassLoader.generateClass(JaxbClassLoader.java:124)
        at
     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateWrapperClass(MappingsGenerator.java:3232)
        at
     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateWrapperClassAndDescriptor(MappingsGenerator.java:3001)
        at
     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.addEnumerationWrapperAndDescriptor(MappingsGenerator.java:2972)
        at
     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.processGlobalElements(MappingsGenerator.java:2919)
        at
     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.MappingsGenerator.generateProject(MappingsGenerator.java:274)
        at
     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.compiler.Generator.generateProject(Generator.java:184)
        at
     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1108)
        at
     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext$TypeMappingInfoInput.createContextState(JAXBContext.java:1100)
        at
     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContext.<init(JAXBContext.java:189)
        at
     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:165)
        at
     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:152)
        at
     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:112)
        at
     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory.createContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:102)
        at
     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.getJAXBContext(MOXyJsonProvider.java:318)
        at
     org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider.readFrom(MOXyJsonProvider.java:633)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.invokeReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:256)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:235)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:74)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:155)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1085)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:852)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerRequest.readEntity(ContainerRequest.java:270)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.inject.EntityParamValueFactoryProvider$EntityValueFactory.provide(EntityParamValueFactoryProvider.java:96)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParamValueFactoryWithSource.provide(ParamValueFactoryWithSource.java:71)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.internal.ParameterValueHelper.getParameterValues(ParameterValueHelper.java:93)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$AbstractMethodParamInvoker.getParamValues(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:127)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:309)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)     at
     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)   at
     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)  at
     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)  at
     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)  at
     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:386)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:334)
        at
     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
        at
     com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
        at
     com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
        at
     org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried to edit `MANIFEST` on glassfish modules, i've added the properties file on model package and the other main solutions found on web but nothing happens. Hoping someone can help me. Thanks in advice.

Comment: have you checked your jar dependencies and class path?

Comment: yes, i've check them..

Comment: what's the  org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb officiale jar?

Comment: It's a Glassfish error in loading libraries..I've switched server to Tomcat and it works fine.